# My app_name is not showing when I lauch the emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

My main.xml is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.qiaoyi.tipcalculator.MainActivity">
```

And my Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.qiaoyi.tipcalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to add android:label="@string/app_name" to my manifest before, but it still does not work. So I take it out. What is the problem with my codes? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by app_name not showing when you launch emulator, can you elaborate..@smart_cookie

Answer (score 0):

What does your `strings.xml` file look like?

Update your app name in the `strings.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My super cool tool</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: My string.xml does look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `label` value in the `manifest`, you must set the definition for the string ***app_name*** in ***/res/values/strings.xml***, this way:

```
<string name="app_name">Your app name</string>
```